# Why aren't we in public beta yet?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, private-beta

I thought the private beta was only supposed to last 7 days. We have been in for 9 days at the time of writing, and we are still in private beta. What are the condidions needed to reach public beta?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about that, folks! We normally do write a post when a private beta is being extended.

Arduino just needs some more time to come up with some additional questions, just to make certain there's plenty of interesting things for folks to do once the doors open. Nothing to be alarmed at, you're doing a great job - just need to build up the base a bit more.

Pops can chime in with any other guidance now that he's feeling better (which is probably what's to blame for you not getting a notice when we decided to extend the private beta).

Our bad.

Answer (score 2):

We've actually been talking about this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13851003#13851003). Apparently the private beta can last up to 2 weeks. If it's performing well, it *is* possible to go public after 1 week though, but it all depends on reviews by the [SE Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do).

From what I've read of other betas, I get the impression we're doing fairly well. There may be some issues regarding our scope though, and the possibility of overlap with existing SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino went into public beta a few hours ago!

Congrats, everyone!